# Set up Apollo-Router with TLS

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation, spring-graphql

I'm having some issues by setting up `apollo-router` 1.9.0 to work with TLS.

I tried to configure `apollo-router` using these configs:

```
tls:
  subgraph:
    subgraphs:
      spring-graphql-service:
        certificate_authorities: "/x/y/z/spring-graph-service_ca.pem"
```

I got this error in `apollo-router`:

```
"level":"ERROR","fields":{"message":"could not create router: could not load certificate authorities: the certificate list is empty"},"target":"apollo_router::executable"}
could not create router: could not load certificate authorities: the certificate list is empty
```

I have successfully validated the certificate path to make sure the certificate exists.

After that, I set the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE to reference to the CA certificate path.

The previous error was gone, but then I started getting this error when I queried the graph router:

```
HTTP fetch failed from 'spring-graphql-service': HTTP fetch failed from 'spring-graphql-service': error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: CaUsedAsEndEntity
```

The certificate I'm using is being successfully used on other services, so the issue might be the way I'm trying to configure the usage of the cert on `apollo-router` or something miss configured on the `spring-graphql-service`.

I appreciate any hint to help me setting up the TLS properly between `apollo-router` and `spring-graphql-service`.